# Python - Open subset of a binary file

Tags: python, file, input, binary, subset

In python if I want to open something in binary I simply do:

```
f = open("myfile.bin", "rb")
```

Then f is an handler, and I can use it to read, detect end of file, seek etc.
Now, what if I wanted to do this on a *subset* of myfile.bin? Something like:

```
f = open("myfile.bin", "rb", beg=1000, end=1100)
```

So that I end up with an handler to some sort of virtual file, of length 100 bytes, that actually maps to a subset of the original file?

I know that if I was to work on the file's content it would be easy: I could just seek around and be careful. But there are several libraries that ask for file handles as inputs, and I would like them to work only on subset of files. Again, I know that I could make a copy of it and make the library read that, but I am working on quite huge files and I would prefer not to have to duplicate files.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not following the question. Why not open the file, seek to the starting offset (which will set the file handle to the correct offset), and then pass the handle to the library?  If this is not good enough, you are going to need to create derived File class that simulates the limited file range you are attempting (which is a bit of a pain -- but not impossible)

Comment: Good! That is exactly what I meant! How is it possible to build such a class?